# How to set width of a flexbox div

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

Please look my `code` in the [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/liorbar03/s5w78fmu/11/).

Now, the output looks like this:

[image: now]

Please help me change the code so it looks like this:

[image]

CSS:

```css
.card {
 display: contents;
}

.card > div {
 width: 150px;
 height: 120px;
 margin: 10px;
}

.breakLine::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
}

.hiddenCard {
 background-color: red;
}

.cardList {
 display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.MemoryGame {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.controlSection {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue",
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New",
    monospace;
}

HTML:
```

```html
 <body>
    <div id="root">
      <div>
        <div class="MemoryGame">
          <h1>Memory Game !</h1>
          <div class="gameWrapper">
            <div class="controlSection">
              <h2>score: 5</h2>
              <h2>level: 3</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="cardList">
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card breakLine">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card breakLine">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card breakLine">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.card {
    display: contents;
}

.card > div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.breakLine::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
}

.hiddenCard {
    background-color: red;
}

.cardList {
    display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;

}
.gameWrapper{
  max-width: 90%;
}
.MemoryGame {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;

}

.controlSection {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 2rem;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue",
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New",
    monospace;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following CSS for the `controlSection`

```
.controlSection {
    width: 660px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;    
}
```

I just set the width to the width of the boxes (150*4 width + margin 10*6 = 660px)  and aligned the container to the middle with `margin: 0 auto;`

This is not really responsive though.

Good luck

Comment: This is a part of my big project. In fact, I chage the number of the red square rows and the number of squares in each row dynamically. So setting 660px is not userful in my case.

Comment: Are you allowed to use javascript or just pure css?

Comment: JS is ok. I can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extra div, to wrap it up all together

```html
<!-- the whole game area, including the white area -->
<div id="main-div">

    <!-- only the area where stuff should be displayed -->
    <!-- the title div and the header div will align accordingly with the width of the game div  -->
    <div id="game-wrapper">

        <div id="title">

            <p>memory game</p>
        </div>

        <div id="header">

            <p>score: 5</p>
            <p>level: 3</p>
        </div>

        <div id="game">
            <!-- actual game -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: using this model, the score and level text will align with the width of the memory game

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: justify-content:space-around;

```
.controlSection {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-around;
   align-items: center;
   flex-direction: row;
 }
```

```css
.card {
 display: contents;
}

.card > div {
 width: 150px;
 height: 120px;
 margin: 10px;
}

.breakLine::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
}

.hiddenCard {
 background-color: red;
}

.cardList {
 display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.MemoryGame {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  
}

.controlSection {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
        <div class="MemoryGame">
          <h1>Memory Game !</h1>
          <div class="gameWrapper">
            <div class="controlSection">
              <h2>score: 5</h2>
              <h2>level: 3</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="cardList">
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card breakLine">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card breakLine">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card breakLine">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

If this does not work for you, you may need to set boundaries by assigning width to the parent container. Like so,

```
   .controlSection {
       display: flex;
       justify-content: space-between;
       align-items: center;
       flex-direction: row;
       width:65%;
       margin: 0 auto;
     }
```

```css
.card {
 display: contents;
}

.card > div {
 width: 150px;
 height: 120px;
 margin: 10px;
}

.breakLine::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
}

.hiddenCard {
 background-color: red;
}

.cardList {
 display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.MemoryGame {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  
}

.controlSection {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  width:65%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="MemoryGame">
          <h1>Memory Game !</h1>
          <div class="gameWrapper">
            <div class="controlSection">
              <h2>score: 5</h2>
              <h2>level: 3</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="cardList">
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card breakLine">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card breakLine">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card breakLine">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: This is not working. First I want to keep the effect of space-between. Second, it is look bad because you can't set the width of "controlSection" div. it depends the width of "cardList" div that change dynamically. https://i.imgur.com/uqMjZ4X.png

Comment: @liorbar Well, the last thing I can suggest is to move controlSection inside cardList with the original setup. Then it will inherit the width of your cardList

Answer (score 0):

The justify-content property is a sub-property of the [Flexible Box Layout module.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

**space-between** items are evenly distributed in the line; the first item is on the start line, the last item on the end line.

**space-around** items are evenly distributed in the line with equal space around them.

Change the justify-content: space-between to space-around. The empty space before the first and after the last item equals half of the space between each pair of adjacent items.

```css
.card {
 display: contents;
}

.card > div {
 width: 150px;
 height: 120px;
 margin: 10px;
}

.breakLine::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
}

.hiddenCard {
 background-color: red;
}

.cardList {
 display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.MemoryGame {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.controlSection {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue",
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New",
    monospace;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <div>
        <div class="MemoryGame">
          <h1>Memory Game !</h1>
          <div class="gameWrapper">
            <div class="controlSection">
              <h2>score: 5</h2>
              <h2>level: 3</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="cardList">
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card breakLine">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card breakLine">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="card breakLine">
                <div class="hiddenCard"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not working. In full screen is look bad. I want the space-between. The problem is the width of the divs. How can I solve it? https://i.imgur.com/uqMjZ4X.png

Comment: Set width to 50% to the **.controlSection** class. To align in center set margin to **margin:0 auto**.  .controlSection {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 50%; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}

Comment: Again in full screen it is not working. This is because we can't set the width in that way. It depends the <cardList/> div width.